# command prompt execution of "pg_ctl" utility

Tags: postgresql

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_ctl reload C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data
```

running this gives error as

> pg_ctl: too many command-line arguments (first is "C:\Program").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_ctl --help` shows:

> ```
> pg_ctl is a utility to initialize, start, stop, or control a PostgreSQL server.
>
> Usage:
>   ...
>   pg_ctl reload   [-D DATADIR] [-s]
> ```

Which means the data directory has to be specified with the `-D` switch. Additionally you need to quote the directory name because of the blanks:

```
pg_ctl reload -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data"
```

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: storing application data in `C:\Program Files` is a really bad idea.</sup>

Comment: But program files is the recommended and default directory when installing it using the installer.

Comment: Does the installer still do that? I though they finally changed that to `%ProgramData%`. But I don't use the installer - and this is just one reason why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quote, because `Program Files` contain space, and space is the separator between arguments

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_ctl reload "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data"
```

Also, from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pg-ctl.html), it seems you should add `-D`

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_ctl reload -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data"
```